# Unable to click button AttributeError: 'Chrome' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click a  button on a website and im unable to do it with this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/button").click()
```

it gives error: `AttributeError: 'Chrome' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'`

it used to work just fine before but now its broken...

Comment: Use driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"") then use the follow import  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: TYSM it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium just removed that method in version `4.3.0`. See the CHANGES: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
* Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
* Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
* Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
* Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
* Improved type hints throughout
```

You now need to use:

```py
driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/button").click()
```

For improved reliability, you should consider using `WebDriverWait` in combination with `element_to_be_clickable`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause either, but I found a solution

origin My Code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-keyword='"+tag+"']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

add Module

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

and Change Code

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-keyword='"+tag+"']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```